# Como converter uma string em objeto JSON

Tags: java, json, api

Eu recebo no `@FormParam` um texto no formato JSON, quero saber como faço pra tornar ele um objeto JSON no Java, para que eu possa manipular os elementos?

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getContadores(@FormParam("Contadores") String Contadores) throws Exception{

        try{


        }catch(Exception e){


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer assim:
Dentro do `try` vai fazer o tratamento.

```
try {
    obj = new JSONObject(jsonResposta);

    JSONArray usuarioJArray = (JSONArray) obj.get("result");
    obj = (JSONObject) usuarioJArray.get(0);
} catch (JSONException e) {
   //erro
}
```

Na primeira linha do `try` eu transformo em um `JSONObject`, se seu JSON não tiver um array pode já trabalhar assim, se tiver como o meu caso eu transformei em um `JSONArray`.

Lendo dados de um `JSONArray`:

```
try {
  JSONArray JArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("produto");
  for (int i = 0; i < JArray .length(); i++) {
    jsonObject = (JSONObject) produtoJArray.get(i);
    value = jsonObject.getDouble(field); //para numeros reais
    value = jsonObject.getInt(field); //para numeros inteiros
    value = jsonObject.getString(field); //para string
}
catch (JSONException je){
            //erro
}
```

Comment: O resultado vai ser um array, ou seja, vai ter varios textos JSON, pois recebo informações de usuarios. Caso eu tenha por exemplo: " { Nome : '', Endereco : { Rua : '', Cidade : '' } } ", ele ira funcionar desse mesmo jeito, pegando o valor apenas setando o campo?

Comment: vai ter que combinar as duas instruções que passei para o endereço, transformando ele em um Array e lendo de novo

Comment: @VictorHenrique `{ Nome : '', Endereco : { Rua : '', Cidade : '' } }` não é um array, pois arrays são delimitados por `[ ]`. O que essa string contém é um objeto, então trate-o com `JSONObject` (essa distinção é importante porque se tratar um array como objeto ou vice-versa, não vai funcionar). Se puder, favor editar a pergunta colocando alguns exemplos de strings e como quer manipulá-las. De qualquer forma, acho que o mais importante é primeiro entender [a sintaxe de um JSON](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-13/como-ler-e-manipular-um-json), aí facilita na hora de fazer o código...

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é que meu texto que esta vindo com parametro será da seguinte forma: [{ Nome : '', Endereco : { Rua : '', Cidade : '' } }] , [{ Nome : '', Endereco : { Rua : '', Cidade : '' } }] , [{ Nome : '', Endereco : { Rua : '', Cidade : '' } }].

Comment: @VictorHenrique Nesse caso, a string possui vários arrays, então criar um único `JSONArray` não vai funcionar (se não me engano, o construtor só vai pegar o primeiro array e ignorar o resto). Eu sugiro que vc [edite a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/380761/edit) e coloque esta string lá, assim as respostas podem focar neste caso específico.